# Modified: Replacing values of rows with identical rownames in a dataframes

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with few rows of identical row names. I want to replace NAs of every second row with the non NA of identical immediate previous row. But if there already exists a value in second row then, it should not be affected.

Please see below:

df:

```
date             1   1   2  3   3

20040101        100 150 NA  NA  140

20040115        200 NA  200 NA  NA

20040131        170 NA  NA  NA  NA
20040131        NA  165 180 190 190

20040205        NA  NA  NA  NA  NA

20040228        140 145 165 150 155
20040228        NA  NA  NA  NA  NA

20040301        150 155 170 150 160

20040315        NA  NA  180 190 200

20040331        NA  145 160 NA  NA
20040331        NA  NA  NA  175 180
```

I want the resulting data frame to be:

df_new:

```
date        1   1   2   3   3

20040101        100 150 NA  NA  140

20040115        200 NA  200 NA  NA

20040131        170 165 180 190 190

20040205        NA  NA  NA  NA  NA

20040228        140 145 165 150 155

20040301        150 155 170 150 160

20040315        NA  NA  180 190 200

20040331        NA  145 160 175 180
```

I have tried the following for loop, but results are not as desired:

for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {

> ```
> if(all(is.na(df[i, ]))){ df[i, ] = fill[(i-1), ]}
> ```
>
> out[i, ]<- df[i-1,ncol]
>   }

Please guide me in this regard.

Thanks 
Saba

Comment: What should I include to make it nice format?

Comment: Paste samples of your data into your question using `dput()`. For example, to provide ten rows of df1, paste in the output of `dput(df1[1:10, ])`. This will make it easy for people to copy and paste your data into their R console.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi: It is not strictly the case where for all NAs of df1 there is a non NA  of df2. In most of the cases both df1 and df2 have NAs in identical rows. But I just want to replace those NAs of df1 which have parallel non NAs of df2 available.

Comment: Is it assured that `df1` and `df2` have no duplicacies as far as row names is concerned?

Comment: @KunalPuri: all the rows in df2 have identical row names as in df1.

Comment: No. My question is that can any single dataframe have two tuples with same name e.g. there may be two tuples in `df1` having same row name?

Comment: Also, is it assured that the tuples you want to be replaced will belong to `df1` only?

Comment: @KunalPuri: No, all the rows have unique names.. because they are actually dates, so they are not identical.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  We place the datasets in a `list`, then make it a single data.table using `rbindlist`, grouped by 'date', loop through the columns (`lapply(.SD, ..`) and subset the non-NA elements.

```
library(data.table)
unique(rbindlist(list(df1, df2))[,lapply(.SD, function(x) 
         if(all(is.na(x))) x else x[!is.na(x)]) , date])
#       date X11A X11A.1 X21B X3CC X3CC.1
#1: 20040101  100    150   NA   NA    140
#2: 20040115  200     NA  200   NA     NA
#3: 20040131  170    165  180  190    190
#4: 20040205   NA     NA   NA   NA     NA
#5: 20040228  140    145  165  150    155
#6: 20040301  150    155  170  150    160
#7: 20040315   NA     NA  180  190    200
#8: 20040331   NA    145  160  175    180
```

---

As the OP noted about using `for` loop and `which`, another option with `data.table` that uses both of them with `set` would be

```
setDT(df1)
dfN <- setDT(df2)[df1, on = "date"]
for(j in 2:ncol(df1)){
  set(df1, i = which(is.na(df1[[j]])), j = j, 
                    value = dfN[[j]][is.na(df1[[j]])])
 }
df1
#       date X11A X11A.1 X21B X3CC X3CC.1
#1: 20040101  100    150   NA   NA    140
#2: 20040115  200     NA  200   NA     NA
#3: 20040131  170    165  180  190    190
#4: 20040205   NA     NA   NA   NA     NA
#5: 20040228  140    145  165  150    155
#6: 20040301  150    155  170  150    160
#7: 20040315   NA     NA  180  190    200
#8: 20040331   NA    145  160  175    180
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[,lapply(.SD,mean,na.rm=T),by=date]

##   date X11A X11A.1 X21B X3CC X3CC.1
##1: 20040101  100    150  NaN  NaN    140
##2: 20040115  200    NaN  200  NaN    NaN
##3: 20040131  170    165  180  190    190
##4: 20040205  NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN    NaN
##5: 20040228  140    145  165  150    155
##6: 20040301  150    155  170  150    160
##7: 20040315  NaN    NaN  180  190    200
##8: 20040331  NaN    145  160  175    180
```

Assumption: Here, I am assuming that in case numerous tuples occur for a single date, each column has only one unique value, otherwise NA.